# Перерисовка Button

Tags: java, android

Суть в чем. Создаю приложение. Добавляю на экран кнопку. Рисую на экране квадрат/круг с помощью отдельного экземпляра класса, унаследованного от View, в методе onDraw на Canvas. Примерно, так:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(new MyView(this));
 }

 public class MyView extends View
 {
     Paint paint = null;
     public MyView(Context context) 
     {
          super(context);
          paint = new Paint();
     }

     @Override
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
     {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int x = getWidth();
        int y = getHeight();
        int radius;
        radius = 100;
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        // Use Color.parseColor to define HTML colors
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
        canvas.drawCircle(x / 2, y / 2, radius, paint);
    }
 }
```

Естественно, кнопку мою затирает квадрат/круг...

Что нужно сделать, чтобы обновить/перерисовать кнопку?

Comment: Покажите разметку layout.

Comment: поместите кнопку в своей разметке по иерархии выше своего кастомного View

Comment: Каким образом? Я рисую все на одном layout

Comment: Сначала рисуйте свое View, потом кнопку

Comment: А если она уже есть? Заново создавать кнопку? Что за бред..